# Multiplying the volume form by the codifferential of a one form yields an exact form

Tags: riemannian-geometry, hodge-theory

Let $(M, g)$ be an oriented Riemannian manifold with volume form $dv$. Let $*$ be the Hodge star operator defined by the relation $\omega \wedge *\tau = g(\omega, \tau) dv$ where $g$ is extended to forms. I know that w.r.t. the global product given by the extension of $g$ to forms, $\delta:= *d*$ is the adjoint of $d$ up to a sign. That is $\int_M g(d\omega, \tau)dv = \int_M g(\omega, \delta \tau)dv$.

I am trying to see that given $\tau \in \Omega^1(M)$, we have that $(\delta \tau) dv = d(*\tau)$ up to a sign. I tried using what I know and got at
$$
(\delta \tau ) dv=
( * d * \tau ) dv =
dv \wedge ( *d* \tau) =
g(dv, d* \tau) dv =
g(\delta dv, *\tau) dv = (\delta dv) \wedge (** \tau)
$$

So, since $** $ is the identity with a sign, $(\delta \tau) dv = (\delta dv) \wedge \tau$ up to sign. This doesn't seem to help, though.

Comment: What is $g(d\omega, \tau)$?

Comment: @ArcticChar Are you asking how is $g$ extended to forms? (Also, I realized that actually $\delta$ is only adjoint to $d$ with respect to the global scalar product, I edited. This also makes the calculation false)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It suffices to use $*1 = dv$, $** = \pm 1$ and $g(\omega, \tau) = g(*\omega, *\tau)$.

\begin{align}
\delta \tau dv &= (\pm *d* \tau) dv\\
&= \pm g(1,* d*\tau)dv \\
&= \pm g(dv, d(*\tau))dv \\
&= \pm g(d(*\tau), dv)dv \\
&= \pm  d(*\tau)\wedge *dv  \\ 
&= \pm d(*\tau)
\end{align}